# using PHP to find exact value in a string

Tags: php, string

the current tasks at hand is using PHP to check if data exists

to make things short the problem is:

i am trying to search some of the available sizes in a unorganized string.

sizes are
SM/M M/L L/XL XS S M L XL XXL 28 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 28 X 30 28 X 32

currently most of the issues are solved by utilizing whitespaces to disgtinush unique variable, but when it comes to (number X number) as a phrase it becomes very difficult.

when I search for "28"  it also detect as found when seeing "28 X 30"
or when I search for unique number " 30 " with the whitespaces included, it still detects the 28 X "30"

Is there any method to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is make the string easier to deal with by first transforming the `nnn X nnn` strings and removing spaces from them:

```
 //BEFORE: SM/M M/L L/XL XS S M L XL XXL 28 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 28 X 30 28 X 32
 //AFTER: SM/M M/L L/XL XS S M L XL XXL 28 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 28X30 28X32
 $sizes=preg_replace('/(\d+) X (\d+)/', '$1X$2', $sizes);
```

Now you can explode the string on spaces

```
 $sizeArray=explode(' ', $sizes);
```

With all the distinct sizes in an array, you can use in_array to look for a specific size code.

```
 //we want to find this
 $searchFor='28 X 30';

 //our codes no longer have spaces...
 $searchFor=str_replace(' ', '', $searchFor);
 if (in_array($searchFor, $sizeArray)) {
      //great!
 }
```